# There is no result type defined for type 'dynamic-jasper' mapped with name 'success'

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am trying to use DynamicJasper 5.0.0 with Struts 2.3.4. I am using following code to show data in PDF format

**In action class**

```
try {
    FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
    DynamicReport dr = drb.addColumn("Size", "size", String.class.getName(), 30).setTitle("Size List Report").setSubtitle("This report was generateed at" + new Date()).setUseFullPageWidth(true) //make colums to fill the page width
            .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true).build();

    JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getSizeList());
    JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), ds);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);    //finally display the report report   [/CODE]  
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
return SUCCESS;
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<package name="expotpkg" extends="struts-default, json-default,jasperreports-default"> 
   <result-types>
        <result-type name="dynamic-jasper" class="ar.com.fdvs.dj.webwork.DJResult"/>
    </result-types>

<action name="DownloadSizePdf" class="iland.work.SizesAction" method="fetchDJ">
            <result name="success" type="dynamic-jasper">
                <param name="dynamicReport">dr</param>
                <param name="dataSource">sizeList</param>
                <param name="documentName">Dynamic Report generated with struts 2</param>
                <param name="parameters">params</param>
                <param name="format">PDF</param>
                <param name="layoutManager">classic</param>
            </result>
        </action>
   </package>
```

While running this I am getting following error

```
There is no result type defined for type 'dynamic-jasper' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'dynamicJasper'? - result - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:571:58
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:653)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:387)
    ... 20 more
```

I have included following jar files
[image]

Comment: You haven't defined `dynamic-jasper` result.

Comment: @AleksandrM How to define it

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration to your package

```xml
<result-types>
    <result-type name="dynamicJasper" class="ar.com.fdvs.dj.webwork.DJResult"/>
</result-types>

<action name="DownloadSizePdf" class="iland.work.SizesAction" method="fetchDJ">
    <result name="success" type="dynamicJasper">
        <param name="dynamicReport">dr</param>
        <param name="dataSource">sizeList</param>
        <param name="documentName">Dynamic Report generated with struts 2</param>
        <param name="parameters">params</param>
        <param name="format">PDF</param>
        <param name="layoutManager">classic</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

---

The `ActionSupport` class is under the package name `com.opensymphony.xwork2`. The error is occurred from the configuration of the plugin you use with Struts2 which is incompatible to the version of Struts you use.

Comment: You have different versions of the dynamic jasper. Use the latest 5.0 only. Try to rename the result type to `dynamicJasper`.

Comment: Not working showing error `There is no result type defined for type 'dynamicJasper' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'dynamicJasper'?`

Comment: I am using DynamicJasper 5.0.0

Comment: I defined result type `dynamicJasper` but it referenced a class from `webwork` package and plugin itself is for WW framework. The Struts version 2.3.4 already doesn't have such packages. The plugin should rework to be compatible with the version of Struts you use.

Comment: You can't use it as is, you might try to refactor it and rebuild by changing package names.